# SQL case statement that returns query based on instances of a row

Tags: sql, database, count, db2, case

I am trying to write a sub query that counts up the number of 'TRACE_NO' and if there is only one instance I want it to display the original string. However, if it has more than one 'TRACE_NO' instance I want the row to display 'Duplicate'. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT 
    SL.FILE_NO AS FILE,
    (SELECT CASE(WHEN TR.TRACE_NO HAVING COUNT(*) >1 THEN 'DUPLICATE' ELSE
TR.TRACE_NO) 
     FROM IASDB.TRACE_DETAIL TR 
     WHERE SL.INVOICE_NO = TR.INVOICE_NO
       AND TR.TRACE_TYPE IN 'XX') AS XX
```

TABLE

```
FILE   XX 
1120 | SEA
1315 | SDF
1251 | SEA
1251 | GEG
1991 | ATL
1235 | BOI
1235 | CVG
```

Desired Output:

```
FILE | XX
1120 | SEA
1315 | SDF
1251 | DUPLICATE
1991 | ATL
1235 | DUPLICATE
```

Comment: Your outer query has no `FROM` clause and `SL` is undefined.

Comment: This is part of a larger query where SL is defined. This is only a snippet. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is part of a larger query, this may be the logic you want:

```
SELECT SL.FILE_NO AS FILE,
       (SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 'DUPLICATE' ELSE MIN(TR.TRACE_NO) END
        FROM IASDB.TRACE_DETAIL TR 
        WHERE SL.INVOICE_NO = TR.INVOICE_NO AND TR.TRACE_TYPE IN 'XX'
       ) AS XX
```

Comment: Yes, it is part of a larger query. I tried this but it gives me this error

Error Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=*) > 1 THEN 'DUPLICATE' ELSE MIN(;ECT CASE(WHEN COUNT(;<space>, DRIVER=4.13.127. 2) [Error Code: -727, SQL State: 56098]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-104;42601;*) > 1 THEN 'DUPLICATE' ELSE MIN(|ECT CASE(WHEN COUNT(|<s, DRIVER=4.13.127

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement this with your logic in the wrapping query like this:

```
SELECT 
  FILE, 
  CASE 
    WHEN CNT = 1 THEN TRACE_NO
    ELSE 'DUPLICATE'
  END AS XX
FROM (
  SELECT SL.FILE_NO AS FILE, TR.TRACE_NO, COUNT(*) as CNT
  FROM IASDB.TRACE_DETAIL TR 
  GROUP BY  SL.FILE_NO AS, TR.TRACE_NO
)
```